# Gitlab JUnit test report statistic over many builds

Tags: gitlab, test-reporting

We set up junit test reporting in gitlab and can see the results in the pipeline.
Is it possible in any way (maybe via API?) to extract a statistic of how often a test fails? For example:

- TestX 0/20 times successful
- TestY 17/20 times successful
- TestZ 19/20 times successful
- ...

Background: we have very many integration tests and some of them show timing issues which cause them to fail. I would like to identify the tests which fail most often.

Comment: have you been able to solve this problem?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc unfortunately, we did not find any solution yet. But we are using a workaround to ease the analysis. We add a ci stage after the testing is done. In that stage, we check the test log and extract all tests which failed. It does not provide a statistic itself, but it is much quicker to see which tests failed.